# Get "Roles and administrators" for Service Principal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-service-principal

In Azure Portal, when I look at a Service Principal's "Roles and administrators" tab I see several roles, including a couple of custom roles:
[image: Azure Portal Roles and administrators]

I can use PowerShell to get the Role Definition:

```
PS C:\> Get-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleDefinition -Filter "DisplayName eq 'My Custom Role'"

Id                                   Description        DisplayName    IsBuiltIn IsEnabled ResourceScopes TemplateId                           Version
--                                   -----------        -----------    --------- --------- -------------- ----------                           -------
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 Used for My Stuff  My Custom Role False     True      {/}            00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

But when I check to see if my Service Principal is assigned the role, it doesn't show up.

```
PS C:\> Get-MgServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalId $ServicePrincipalId 

Id                                   DisplayName          AppId                                SignInAudience
--                                   -----------          -----                                --------------
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 my-service-principal 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 AzureADMyOrg

PS C:\> Get-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleAssignment -Filter "principalId eq '$ServicePrincipalId'"
PS C:>
```

Or, if I use the GUID for the Role to see everybody that is assigned that role, I still get nothing:

```
PS C:> Get-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleAssignment -Filter "RoleDefinitionId eq '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'"
PS C:>
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

***Note**: I get similar results using `Get-AzureADMSRoleDefinition` etc.*

Comment: I think the roles listed there are not roles that have been assigned to the service principal, but are roles that would give access to manage that service principal if assigned to a user or service principal.

Comment: That would explain what I am getting.
However, if I do
`PS C:> Get-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleAssignment -Filter "RoleDefinitionId eq '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'"`


With the GUID for my Role, nothing shows shows up either.



That being said, is there anyway to get a list of the Roles that a Service Principal has?

Comment: I updated the question above with this info.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have one application named `SriApp` with roles as below:

[image]

When I ran same commands as you, I got the **response** successfully with list of roles assigned to service principal like this:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Directory.Read.All"
Get-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleDefinition -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Devi Custom role'"
$ServicePrincipalId = "35cf4958-adcf-4c07-891b-dxxxxxxxx"
Get-MgServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalId $ServicePrincipalId 
Get-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleAssignment -Filter "principalId eq '$ServicePrincipalId'"
Get-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleAssignment -Filter "RoleDefinitionId eq '74d0febe-1007-4ff4-a793-753cxxxxxxx'"
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, you can check active assignments in PIM by searching with application name like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Privileged Identity Management -> Azure AD roles -> Assignments -> Active assignments*

[image]

If you select scope as **Directory** level while assigning roles, they will be reflected under every application but not assigned in real.

When I checked another application named `Sri`, it has same roles as below even I did not assign them manually:

[image]

Now, I ran same commands changing `$ServicePrincipalId` with above application and got **same response** as you without any results like below:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Directory.Read.All"
Get-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleDefinition -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Devi Custom role'"
$ServicePrincipalId = "7b6320e7-19ab-496c-b1c8-dxxxxxxxxxx"
Get-MgServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalId $ServicePrincipalId 
Get-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleAssignment -Filter "principalId eq '$ServicePrincipalId'"
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, confirm whether the service principal is assigned with roles or not by checking **active assignments** in PIM with it's name and give **valid** service principal ID to list roles.